# iOS/Swift - Programming an "app" directly in the control center

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, prototype, control-center

Is it possible to get into programming an extension for the control center in Swift? Not something like the widget spotify provides but one level above.

How I have to think about it? Is it neccessary to have an app like "Calculator" so that you can create a button for it in the control center or are there other possibilities like creating a fully fledged app but making it possibly invisible, like "Screen Recorder"?

As far as I know, a collegue of mine showed me some custom stuff but it was available due to a Jailbreak I think.

Comment: Are you talking about the interface that appears when you swipe up from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: All iOS extensions must be contained in an app, otherwise there is no way for the user to install or uninstall them.  The Control Center is not something that apps can extend. You can add "today" widgets

Comment: @matt Depending on the OS, yes. With my iPhone 11, newest OS, it is a swipe from the top **right** corner to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Well, if we’re talking about the same thing, then no, you can’t add anything to that interface. The user can modify it, but only Apple can supply the options.